# How to Check Python3 Process running on macOS background terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, zsh

I'm running one python script using : nohup -  python3 name.py >/dev/null &  - to run one script in the background of my terminal. However would like to know best command to see a list of just python3 process running. i tried ps -xal|grep python3 (what i use on Linux) but was not working.

Thanks a lot ! :/)